# Linq EF --> Contains condition does not work

Tags: entity-framework, linq, lambda, contains

I have a problem: I have this table

| ID | Title | GenreID | Genre | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Movie1 | 1,2 | Cartoon, Family | 80 |
| 2 | Movie2 | 3,4 | Horror, Drama | 76 |
| 3 | Movie3 | 4 | Drama | 110 |
| 4 | Movie4 | 1,2 | Cartoon, Family | 200 |

I need to filter by Genre, I make my query in this way, For example if I want all movies with Genre Cartoon (2), I make:

request.genre = 2

```
var query1 = from q in Movies
     select new Response.MovieResponse
     {
         MovieId = q.MovieId,
         Name = q.Title,
         Genres = q.Genre,
         GenreIds = q.GenreID                             
     };
        

if (request != null)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Title))
        query1 = query1.Where(co => co.Name.StartsWith(request.name));

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.genre))
        if (int.Parse(request.genre) > 0)
        {
            query1.AsEnumerable().Where(ca => 
                request.genre .Any(x => ca.GenreIds.Contains(x)));                        
        }
}

List<Response.StoreResponse> stores = new List<Response.StoreResponse>();            
stores = await query1.ToListAsync();
```

I expected 2 records inside but the filter on genre does not work. I always have back all movies. The filter by title run

I tried

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.category))
                if (int.Parse(request.category) > 0)
                {
                    string[] cat = { request.category };
                    var q1 = query1.Where(ca => ca.CategoriesIds.Contains(cat.ToString()));
                    l = q1.ToList();                        
                }
```

but I have error:

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Store>()
.Join(
    inner: DbSet<Country>(), 
    outerKeySelector: s => s.CountryId, 
    innerKeySelector: c => (Nullable<int>)c.CountryId, 
    resultSelector: (s, c) => new TransparentIdentifier<Store, Country>(
        Outer = s, 
        Inner = c
    ))
.Join(
    inner: DbSet<City>(), 
    outerKeySelector: ti => ti.Outer.CityId, 
    innerKeySelector: c0 => (Nullable<long>)c0.CityId, 
    resultSelector: (ti, c0) => new TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<Store, Country>, City>(
        Outer = ti, 
        Inner = c0
    ))
.Where(ti0 => ti0.Outer.Outer.StatusId == (Nullable<int>)2)
.Where(ti0 => DbSet<Operator>()
    .Where(o => EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(ti0.Outer.Outer, "StoreId") != null && object.Equals(
        objA: (object)EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(ti0.Outer.Outer, "StoreId"), 
        objB: (object)EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(o, "StoreId")))
    .Count() > 0)
.Where(ti0 => string.Join<long>(
    separator: ",", 
    values: DbSet<StoresCategory>()
        .Where(s0 => EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(ti0.Outer.Outer, "StoreId") != null && object.Equals(
            objA: (object)EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(ti0.Outer.Outer, "StoreId"), 
            objB: (object)EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(s0, "StoreId")))
        .Select(s0 => s0.CategoryId)
        .ToList()).Contains(__ToString_0))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Comment: Can you show your ca.GenreIds pls?

Comment: You can't be using `=` in C# for a test. Your `if` for testing genre has a no effect statement - you don't assign the result of the `AsEnumerable().Where()` to anything so it is ignored.

Comment: Hi @Sergey thanks for your message. The GenreIds is a string with all ids for example for the first records is "1,2"

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer too.

Comment: Hi @Sergey I tried but I have error.